# How to build and configure an angular 12 sub-application in IIS?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-5

My iis setup looks like this:

[image]

Cool App is an umbrella/container application used as a dashboard to lunch sub/children apps. "Child Cool App" was created with .net 5 and Angular 12 in visual studio. Moving the application to a child of "Domain Web Site" with `<base href="./">`index.html base ref  actually works, but moving it as a child of "Cool App" has proven tricky for the last couple of days.

Have tried:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href /child cool app/
Index.html: <base href="/">
Index.html: <base href="">
Index.html: <base href="/child cool app/">
Index.html: <base href="./">
```

The 2 projects live in completely different folders and are referenced in iis by their physical paths. Keep getting the "This localhost page can’t be found"

Thanks...

Comment: URLs and folder names shouldn't contain spaces... What happens if you rename `child cool app` to something like `child-cool-app`?

Comment: Thanks .... those are not actually the names of the applications, just made up names as example. The real ones are more like app1\app2

Comment: According to your description, it is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it just stated working. Following configuration worked:

- In angular.json architect\build\options\baseref =
  "/cool_app/cool_child_app/"
- Perform a regular publish from Visual Studio (2019)
- IIS create application below (cool_app\cool_child_app) with its own app
  pool
- IIS, point to your published folder